# Any HTTP header field for created at semantic?

Tags: rest, http-headers, asp.net-web-api

Like the `Last-Modified` HTTP header field for *updated at*, is there a special one for *created at*?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the use case? For all headers see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: This would be to remove the keys "created_at" and "updated_at" from the JSON of my represented resources. I didn't find a header for created at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header `Last-Modified` has [this meaning](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The Last-Modified entity-header field indicates the date and time at which the origin server believes the variant was last modified.

It is used in the process called 'Conditional GET'.

### Client

The client alread accessd the resource in the past. If it now requests the resource again, it sets the `If-Modified-Since` header:

```
GET /path/to/resource
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT
```

### Server

If the resource has not been modified on the server since this date, the server responds with no body:

```
304 Not Modifed
```

### Summary

The `Last-Modified` has a special meaning which is used enable caching. There is no header to indicate the creation date of a resource.